# unable to do inline edit using react js as getting Warning: Failed prop type

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here I am trying to display a data in to the table and along with that, I am doing an *update*, *append*, *edit* and *delete* operations. All the functionalities are working fine except the *edit*, whenever I click on the *edit* I am getting this error:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: You provided a `value` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultValue`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`
```

I tried setting a default value option but the problem is that after clicking on the *edit* and updating the value it is taking the old value. If you click on edit and edit *55* to *56* then click on save, 55 remains not updated to 56.

```
<tbody>
  {this.state.employeeResponse.map((response, index) => {
    return (
      <tr key={index}>
        <td >{index + 1}</td>
        <td >{response.id}</td>
        <td >{response.employee_name}</td>
        <td > {index !== this.state.isEditable ? <span>{response.employee_salary}</span> : <input type="text" ref={this.empSalary} value={response.employee_salary} id="empSalary" />}</td>
        <td > {index !== this.state.isEditable ? <span>{response.employee_deportment}</span> : <input type="text" ref={this.empDeportment} value={response.employee_deportment} id="empDeportment" />}</td>
        <td>
          {
            index !== this.state.isEditable ? <button className="button-group action-button edit-button-group" onClick={() => this.editEmployee(index)} >Edit</button> : <button className="button-group action-button save-button-group" onClick={() => this.saveEmployeeDetails(index)} >Save</button>
          }
          {
            index !== this.state.isEditable ? <button className="button-group action-button delete-button" onClick={() => this.deleteEmployee(response.id)} >Delete</button> : <button className="button-group action-button cancel-button-group" onClick={this.cancelEmployeeDetails}>Cancel</button>
          }
        </td>
      </tr>
    )
  })}
</tbody>
```

stackblitz --> https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-5aye7d

To view the data click on load button and then click edit to see error

Answer (score 1):

You need to add onChange property to input tab.

If you specify value without onChange the input will work as a read only field.

```
<input type="text" ref={this.empSalary}  value={response.employee_salary} onChange={(e) => {/* update data*/}} id="empSalary" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set State again to change the text inside Input box. 
Can try below code.

```
<td > {index !== this.state.isEditable?<span>{response.employee_deportment}</span>: 
<input type="text" ref={this.empDeportment} value={response.employee_deportment}  
id="empDeportment" 
onChange={(event)=>{
                              let data = this.state.employeeResponse;
                              data[index].employee_deportment = event.target.value
                              this.setState({employeeResponse: data})
}}/>}
</td>
```